# Date validation date picker

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and am trying to find a date picker that displays todays date when it is first loaded and then when a person selects a date it notifies the user with an alert if the date before todays date. Does anyone have any clues as to where I could find some help on building this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Of Course, i would recommend having a look at jQuery UI's Datepicker:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

It lets you specify a minDate, so that the user cannot select any date before the specified mindate.